# Sublime Text set key binding for Tools > Babel > Babel Transform

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a key binding in Sublime Text 3 for the command `Tools > Babel > Babel Transform`.

I have used the menu item `Preferences > Key Bindings` to open the user keymap, and I have added this line:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "babel_transform" },
```

However, pressing Ctrl-Shift-B has no effect. If I use a different command (such as `"prompt_open_folder"`), the key binding words correctly, so I assume that it is the `"babel_transform"` command which I have got wrong.

How should I write this keymap line correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command for Babel Transform is `babel` therefore, this will work:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "babel" }
```

The way figure out a command is to:

1. Open console and turn on logging of commands:
   `sublime.log_commands(True)`
2. Then `Tools > Babel > Babel Transform`
3. The output will be: `command: babel`