# sublime key binding for plugin commands

Tags: json, keyboard, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I did see:

- [Sublime text: how to add a key binding to hex_viewer package command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885473/sublime-text-how-to-add-a-key-binding-to-hex-viewer-package-command)
- [Sublime Text set key binding for Tools > Babel > Babel Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763197/sublime-text-set-key-binding-for-tools-babel-babel-transform)

---

I have installed [JSON Reindent](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSON%20Reindent) in my Sublime (3.2.2 Build 3211). To reindent a JSON I press `Ctrl+Shift+P` type in `JSON Reindent` in command pallet and press enter.

I would like to bind a key combo say `Ctrl+Shift+J` to JSON Reindent command. I already have my own `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` in the right place with a lot of overrides. But I'm unable to find command name.

This functionality is brought in by a plugin so command won't be [available here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/1/commands). I tried to:

- bind `indent` and `reindent`, no luck
- bind `json_reindent`, `JSON_Reindent` and `JSON Reindent`, no luck
- enable command logging via `sublime.log_commands(True)` in cosole, then did

  - `Ctrl+A` (select all)
  - `Ctrl+Shift+P`
  - type in `JSON Reindent` in command pallet
  - press `Enter`

It printed following in console (nothing for JSON reindent).

```
>>> sublime.log_commands(True)
command: move_to {"extend": true, "to": "eol"}
command: select_all
command: show_overlay {"overlay": "command_palette"}
```

What do I put for `command` to bind a plugin's command in my `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap`?

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+j"], "command": "?????" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is found in the plugin's [`sublime_json_reindent.py`](https://github.com/ThomasKliszowski/json_reindent/blob/master/sublime_json_reindent.py) file and is, in fact, called as `sublime_json_reindent`. It can also be found in the [`Default.sublime-commands`](https://github.com/ThomasKliszowski/json_reindent/blob/master/Default.sublime-commands) file.

Comment: Should've thought of looking through the code. Nice!